# I created a database and a table on workbench and immediately I insert values into that table using a query it crashes, I'm using a Mac m1

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

so i just started learning sql using workbench and after I used a query to create a database and table, i used to insert into employee values (value1, value2, value) and everytime i execute it, my workbench just shuts down

i have tried restarting the app, i have installed and uninstalled but nothing is working